# Ajax requests to database inside of requestAnimationFrame loop stopping it from being asynchronous and limiting it to one call if player is moving

Tags: javascript, ajax, requestanimationframe, game-loop

I am currently working on an RPG game and am as of now implementing the NPC system into the world. The world is a tile map system using javascript & canvas, and because this game is text based I have the NPC’S stored in the database (MYSQL). Each ‘npc’ is stored with an x & y coordinate, based on the players position on the map. Each time the player moves an Ajax request is sent, which pulls the data and allows me to push it to the view. NOTE - I am using VUE as my javascript framework and Laravel as the backend.

Anyways the data is requesting fine and I am getting it to show on the view fine - except for one issue. I am using requestAnimationFrame to run my main loop. The loop renders the map, updates the camera position, and moves the player.. Now that I need to implement the NPC’s into the world, those need to update as well whenever the player moves. So because of this, the Ajax request is inside of the requestAnimationFrame loop. As you probably are already guessing, that means that because Ajax is async to begin with, by the time the player moves, they might be already be moving again, and maybe 25 other times - Which means the Ajax call is going to continuously make those requests, which makes it is VERY VERY behind.

As of now I have tried to stop the animation loop, use promises, defering, switching to web sockets (still need to send an Ajax request to broadcast the socket). I am going crazy.

So my question is How can I limit the amount to 1 request at a time for the npc’s in the database. How do I even sneak that into the game loop? No matter what I do the frame will keep moving, but its not even about that, its about stopping the request if the player starts moving again.

I was thinking about just making a database pull and grab every single mob that is in the current ‘map’ area. That way I won’t need to send Ajax requests except for during the mount() or created().

Ps: I am sorry I am trying to figure out the best way to even word this (its my first question I have ever asked, I apologize if its not up to standards.)

Here is a quick draft example of how the update/loop/ajax all interplay. As I mentioned earlier, it is wrapped inside of a Vue js component & instance. Even if you don't know anything about vue and how it works, the functions are what is important here.

```
/* VUE COMPONENT */

Vue.component({

  methods: {

      updateNPC() {

        /* This is where I send over the URL to the vue instance */
        /* it's the url that is needed for the ajax request */

        this.$emit('send', 'url_here_with_x/y_coordinates')

      },

      update() {
        // updates ---- then --

        this.updateNPC()

      },

      render() {
        // render map & player
      },

      loop() {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.loop)
        // keyboard press,
        // {
        //   update
        //   render
        // }
      },

      init() {
        this.update()
        this.draw()
        requestAnimationFrame(this.loop)
      }
    },

    mounted() {
      this.init()
    }

  })

  /* VUE INSTANCE */

  new Vue({

    el: '#world',

    data: {
      mobs: []
    },

    methods: {
      sendNPC(url) {
        /* ajax request using axios */
        /* 
           this Ajax call will send 1000 requests if thats 
           how many times I move, and it will take forever to 
           catch up. this is what I need to fix. 
        */
        axios(url)
      }
    },

    created() {
      /* Laravel Echo Websocket */
      Echo.join('mobs').listen('Mobs', (e) => {
        this.mobs = e.mobs;
      });
    }

  })
```

Again I apologize I have never asked a question here and In general I am awful at expressing haha. But I tried! If I need to provide anything else I will! Hopefully I expressed it enough to where someone can see what I am getting at and can help me solve this annoyance (at least to me!) Thanks!

Comment: Its hard to tell without more details, but you may have better luck separating your game state from your render loop. That way, you may be able to emit an event when an NPC appears, make an ajax call, update your game state, and then render.